# Photoshop-like image difference with Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I want to compare to images of the same size with some text on it.
Let's say the two words are: 'google' and 'gooogle'.
Before measuring the image difference in PS, I am blurring the images using Gauß.

The neat thing in PS is, no matter how you arrange the layers - gooogle on top or google on top - the difference of the layers stay the same.
You get a black background and the difference as (more or less) white pixels.

I am unable to reproduce this functionality in Python.
How did PS manage to get commutativity in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution:
**You need to take the absolute.** Problem is, you need to convert the RGB image (uint8) to a bigger datatype.
After that you can subtract the images and take the absolute. In the end you need to convert it back to RGB, which is uint8.

```
def ps_like_diff:(img1, img2):
    img1_ = img1.astype(int)
    img2_ = img2.astype(int)
    diff = img1_ - img2_
    return (np.abs(diff)).astype('uint8')
```